# How to output NPM packages with peer dependencies that allow for selective imports?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, peer-dependencies

I am publishing a module that uses a few peer dependencies:

In my package.json file i declare peerDependencies:

```
...
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": ">=16",
  "react-dom": ">=16",
  "@material-ui/core": ">=4",
  "@material-ui/icons": ">=4"
},
...
```

And in my webpack config I declare externals along with an output format of `commonjs2` (I'm not at all sure why I would use `commonjs2` instead of `commonjs`):

```
...
output: {
  filename: 'index.js',
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  path: path.join(__dirname, output),
},
externals: {
  react: 'react',
  'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  '@material-ui/core': '@material-ui/core',
  '@material-ui/icons': '@material-ui/icons',
},
...
```

That seems to be working in that I can see the externals are NOT included in the output file. However, including the output of this package in my project results in a MUCH larger bundle size.

I think it's because the output of the bundle converts my `import` statements to `require` statements, so that in my project where I'm using this package the peer dependencies defined as `require` statements can't be optimized.

In other words, the output of the package, instead of including the `@material-ui/core` library as part of the build, will instead reference it as `require('@material-ui/core')`

Is that correct?

What is the correct way to package peer dependencies so that:

1. They adhere to the commonjs module format (is this necessary)?
2. Indirect imports of the peer dependencies can still be selective?

I THINK (but could be wrong) that what is happening at the moment is that:

```
// In my project where I consume the package
import { Thing } from '@org/package-name'

// And in @org/package-name` source code, I have
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core'

// Which gets transpiled to (more or less)
require('@material-ui/core').Card

// Which means that when I use "Thing", that I'm loading the whole of @material-ui/core
```

I've also tried configuring babel with `babel-plugin-transform-imports`. But I'm finding that I would then have to configure the peer dependencies / externals for every import (`@material-ui/core/Card`, `@material-ui/core/List`, etc. etc.)

Comment: Currently the simplest solution seems to just NOT specify peer dependencies, since then my workflow should result in deduplicating imports...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution, I have found, is to set targets.esmodules to true in the babel configuration for preset-env.

I think that the reason this worked for me is that I was re-exporting modules in a single entry. And the named exports in the commonjs format can't easily be isolated on import?

But that's just a guess.